# Delete Alternate Nodes: the compiler is getting me wrong answer idk why

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

*Given a Singly Linked List of size N, delete all alternate nodes of the list.*

Example 1:

***Input:***
LinkedList: 1->2->3->4->5->6
Output: 1->3->5
Explanation: Deleting alternate nodes
results in the linked list with elements
1->3->5.

**my code**

```
class Solution {
    
    public void deleteAlternate (Node head){
        //Write your code here
        Node a = head;
        int i = 0;
        
        while(a!= null){
            if(i%2==0){
                System.out.print(a.data+" ");
            }
            i++;
            a = a.next;
            
        }
        
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

> 

***my output***

*For Input:

6

1 2 3 4 5 6

your output is:

1 3 5

1 2 3 4 5 6*

Comment: You do not delete anything from the list, you just manually print the alternate nodes once. The assignment context is probably: `printList(list); deleteAlternate(list); printList(list);` and your `deleteAlternate` does not delete but only print.

Comment: What do you mean by "the compiler is getting me wrong answer idk why"

Comment: how do i do it @luk2302?

Comment: Well, that is exactly the assignment, you did not really attempt a solution to that, you are on your own for now.

Comment: the answer i am getting is wrong @dreamcrash

Comment: The list is like 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null just skip the element in the middle but pointing to the next element instead 1 -> 3 -> null

Comment: What dreamcrash meant is that the compiler is the wrong to blame here, the compiler only compiles your program, it does not run it, it does not process any program input / output. Your program is simply wrong, nothing to do with the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is just printing all elements at odd positions in your list. However, you are expected to modify the list. Here is an example of steps which can be performed to remove the element "2" from the list:

- When on element "1", you read the link to the next element which should be deleted (element "2")
- You read the link from the element "2" to the next element "3"
- You save the link to element "3" into the "next" field of the element "1", so now the next element for "1" will be "3".

Comment: Good answer in this situation. You did not give away the code, but still explained what to do.